# Android databinding with same layout in different modules

Tags: android, android-databinding

Supposedly I have two android modules

**ModuleA

 - HelloWorld.Xml

ModuleB

 - HelloWorld.Xml**

Notice I have same xml layouts in different modules.

Now there will be two item bindings generated that would also be properly kept in their corresponding module

**ModuleA

 - HelloWorld.Xml

 - HelloWorldItemBinding.java

ModuleB

 - HelloWorld.Xml

 - HelloWorldItemBinding.java**

This compiles however when we land on ModuleB's HelloWorld.xml we get an error with the following

**Cannot cast ModuleA.HelloWorldItemBinding to ModuleB.HelloWorldItemBinding.**

I understand that this is because the project's modules are actually merged at compile time , however I still dont understand that when two binding files are actually created already at build time , why does android have an issue with finding the right one ?.

Also I couldn't find any link on this subject about databindings in multiple modules caveats at the official documentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, a binding class is generated based on the name of the layout file but you can set custom binding class name or full package name to avoid conflict.

ModuleA

```
<data class="HelloWorldModuleA">
…
</data>
```

ModuleB

```
<data class="HelloWorldModuleB">
…
</data>
```

here is official [info](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/generated-binding#custom_binding_class_names)